# How to find median value by using java stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How to find median value by using java stream API :

For example I have the following array `int []arr ={0,1,2,4,6,5,3};`

Is there a way and what is the best way to find the median value using java Stream API;

```
  int findMedian() {
        int []arr ={0,1,2,4,6,5,3};
        IntStream.of(arr).sorted() // what I have to do here
        return 0;
    }
```

And what do you think if I changed to a parallel stream for the big array, will it be faster or not ? Is sorting will be on parallel?

Comment: Especially for a small array, the overhead of dispatching your work to multiple threads in parallel is likely to vastly outweigh the benefits. In practice you should basically always benchmark usages of `parallelStream()` to ensure it's what you want.

Comment: No this is an example, what if we need to for 1 m values?, is the sorting will be on parallel ?

Comment: You'd almost certainly be better off just directly calling `Arrays.sort` or `Arrays.parallelSort`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you pass the array to `findMedian` (and since it doesn't access any fields, make it static). Then you could sort it, convert that back to an array and return the element at half the length. Like,

```
static int findMedian(int[] arr) {
    return IntStream.of(arr).sorted().toArray()[arr.length / 2]);
}
```

**or**, `skip` that many elements and `limit` it to the first result. Like,

```
return IntStream.of(arr).sorted().skip(arr.length / 2).limit(1);
```

Comment: Nice, what do you think if I changed to be parallel stream , will it be faster or not ?

Comment: @AhmadAl-Kurdi For seven values? Slower I would think. There's overhead to starting threads.

Comment: No this is an example, what if we need to for 1 m values?, is the sorting will be on parallel ?

Comment: @AhmadAl-Kurdi if you have a really large array, use `Arrays.parallelSort` to sort that array, instead of making multiple copies using the Stream API.